# Counting the points of intersection

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, computability

A set of equations is given as follows:

$$ x^{\Omega}+y^{\Omega}=1 $$

$$ (1-x)^{\Omega}+y^{\Omega}=1 $$

$$ x^\Omega+(1-y)^\Omega=1 $$

$$ (1-x)^\Omega+(1-y)^\Omega=1. $$

$(\Omega\subset\Bbb Q) =\{1.1,1.2,1.3,...,N\},$ where $N\in\Bbb N$. In the equations, $x,y \in \Bbb A(0,1),$ where A is the set of algebraic numbers.

I was able to calculate the cardinality of $\Omega:$

$|\Omega|=(20(N-1))^2.$ This is the number of intersection points in the inner grid.

Copy the structure $K$ times, which includes the original, and rotate each structure such that all corner points are equally spaced apart. For example when $K=2,$ you would rotate the copied structure by $\pi/4$ radians. When $K=3,$ you would rotate the first copy by $\pi/4$ and the second copy by $\pi/8.$ When $K=3$ you would rotate the first copy by $\pi/4$ the second copy by $\pi/8$ and the third copy by $\pi/16.$

The rotation scheme is as follows:

$$ A=(y-\frac{1}{2})\cos(z)+(x-\frac{1}{2})\sin(z)+\frac{1}{2} $$

$$ B=(x-\frac{1}{2})\cos(z)-(y-\frac{1}{2})\sin(z)+\frac{1}{2}. $$

Then we have the first copy of the original structure as: $$ A^\Omega +B^\Omega=1 $$

$$ (1-A)^\Omega +B^\Omega=1 $$

$$ A^\Omega +(1-B)^\Omega=1 $$

$$ (1-A)^\Omega +(1-B)^\Omega=1. $$

The amounts of rotation for each structure can be expressed by the series:

$$ \pi\sum_{s=2}^K \frac{1}{2^s}=\pi (\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+...+\frac{1}{2^K}).$$

As you can see, for $K=2$ total structures, the sum is $\frac{\pi}{4}$ which tells you to rotate the first copy by that amount.

Taking infinite structures, the angle of rotation goes to zero and the sum of all rotations converges to $\frac{\pi}{2}:$

$$ \pi\sum_{s=2}^\infty \frac{1}{2^s}=\frac{\pi}{2}. $$

How many total intersections occur for a given $K$ and $N$?

How many intersections of degree $D$ are there for a given $K$ and $N$? What is $\max\{D\}$ for a given $K$ and $N?$

This is $K=4$ and the number of curves is about $392.$

[image]

This is $K=1$ and the number of curves is about $60.$

[image]

Comment: If $\Omega$ is a set of $N$ elements then there are $N$ equations of that form

Comment: A structure is a set of the four equations

Comment: I'll elaborate on the rotation of the structures. You have stated the cardinality of half of a structure. I could have defined a structure that way but I chose to define $1$ structure by twice what you have stated

Comment: Yes you're right technically there are $4|\Omega|$ equations